# Contents of a .txt looks gibberish whose content is written using C

Tags: c, structure, file-handling

For learning purposes, I am writing a student record in file called "record.txt" 
and I don't really see any problem in my code(In my opinion).

Here is the code I tried:

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char choice = 'y';

    struct student {
        char name[50];
        int rollno;
        float percentage;
    };
    struct student s;


fp = fopen("record.txt", "w");
if(fp == NULL) {
    puts("Unable to open the file");
    exit(0);
}

while(choice == 'y') {

printf("Enter name, rollno and percentage of student: ");
scanf("%s %d %f", &s.name, &s.rollno, &s.percentage);

fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, fp);

printf("Want to enter another record(y/n): ");

fflush(stdin);
choice = getchar();

}
fclose(fp);

}
```

Output:

```
Enter name, rollno and percentage of student: jon
15
87.2
Want to enter another record(y/n): n

--------------------------------
Process exited after 6.154 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Contents of "record.txt" file:

```
jon            ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿL              ù$@     L      ff®B
```

So, what I am really wondering is that name is written as it should be but other values like rollno and percentage looks unintelligible. Why is this so?

PS feel free to edit the title of question because I didn't found any suitable title for this.

Comment: Looks about right.  Since you use `fwrite()`, the binary version of the structures is written to the file.  Don't use `fwrite()` if you want printable output in the file; use `fprintf()` instead.

Comment: Think about how is `sizeof(s)` and `strlen(s.name)` related. Is the s.name always and exactly 50 characters?

Comment: @KamilCuk I aleady declared a character array i.e. `char name[50];`

Comment: But you don't want to put 50 `char`s in the file when the name is "John", do you?

Comment: @Swordfish Of course, not.

Comment: That is what binary data written by fwrite() looks like when you use a text editor.  Use fprintf() to output text to a .txt file.  And "wt" in the fopen() call.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler problem is solved by using `fprintf()` instead of `fwrite()` but I used `fwrite()` because In my book the author says *using `fprintf()` is inefficient because it stores the numbers as character array i.e., `123456` will be stored as 6 bytes instead of just 2 bytes.*

Comment: @dave Whatever book you're getting that advice from sounds like it was written 30 years ago where every byte was precious. Today we have terabyte sized drives that cost less than a nice pair of socks.

Comment: You can have efficient or you can have readable; it is hard to have both.  The integer will use 4 bytes with `fwrite()`; it will also use 4 bytes for the `float` (de facto values; the C standard doesn't guarantee those numbers).  If the book mentions 2 bytes, I'm left wondering how old it is — it probably dates back to the last millennium. Also, using `fwrite()` requires 50 bytes for the string, even though "`Jon`" only requires 3 or 4 bytes as text — a disparity that completely swamps the 'extra space' used by the numbers. And there could be a couple of padding bytes between name and numbers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I got your point but why the `name` has been written normal and `rollno` and `percenatge` doesn't with `fwrite()` ?

Comment: To a first approximation, the binary and text representations of text are “the same”.  You’d get some better insight if you initialized the name field with, say, the letters of the alphabet and then read the name and wrote the file using `ferrite()`, and then looked at the content of the file.

Comment: Well, I think I am *pretty clear* what I am asking and not sure why this question is "on hold". Anyway I got useful comments and answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the fixed code:

```
# include<stdio.h>
# include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char choice = 'y';

    struct student {
        char name[50];
        int rollno;
        float percentage;
    };
    struct student s;


    fp = fopen("record.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        puts("Unable to open the file");
        exit(0);
    }

    while (choice == 'y') {

        printf("Enter name, rollno and percentage of student: ");
        scanf("%50s %d %f", &s.name, &s.rollno, &s.percentage);

        fprintf(fp, "%s, %d, %f\n", s.name, s.rollno, s.percentage); // !changed

        printf("Want to enter another record(y/n): ");

        fflush(stdin);
        choice = getchar();

    }
    fclose(fp);

}
```

Especially the line 
`fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, fp);` needs to be changed.

- use `fprintf()` to write human readable data
- also you need to not
  write the bit pattern of the struct, but instead access each field of
  the struct.

-> `fprintf(fp, "%s, %d, %f\n", s.name, s.rollno, s.percentage);`

Also another minor thing, if you use `scanf("%50s %d %f", &s.name, &s.rollno, &s.percentage);` you limit the size of the read `name` to 50 characters, preventing buffer overflow.